# Нужно сделать live обновление текста в блоке html

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, get

Как только в базу данных вводиться новое значение, на сайте моментально меняется текст в блоке. Реализовал через отправку ajax запросов c интервалом 500, но мне кажется это можно оптимизировать и не отправлять каждые пол секунды запрос на сервер.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону cron

Comment: А зачем такая маленькая задержка? Если у Вас чат думаю стоит посмотреть в сторону сокетов, остальные или по определённым событиям, или сделайте задержку длительней

Comment: Выложите код записи в БД. В каком случае производится запись в БД? При нажатии кнопки, переходе по ссылке или другие варианты? Постарайтесь выкладывать больше информации, чтобы Вам смогли быстрее помочь. Если задача сделать без перезагрузки страницы, а на клиентской стороне - можно использовать addEventListener. Без понимания кода сложно сказать точно, а предлагать всё подряд - не рентабельно.

Comment: @Denisxyz при чем тут запись в БД? добавляет туда один, обновляется  других.автор уже использует аякс.

Comment: вариантов у вас не так и много, обычный аякс у вас есть уже. можете лонг-поллинг сделать. У SSE проблемы с совместимостью. остается еще сокеты, если хостинг позволяет.

Comment: @Gronify при том, что данные можно передавать при нажатии кнопки, при созданной записи или при запросе в БД.  В случае записи данных в базу данных, можно сразу проставлять значение переменной, которую будет слушать addEventListener, а не отправлять множество запросов к серверу для проверки изменений!